# PLC programming: Conversion to datatype of same size and back changes actual value

Tags: types, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, plc, st

A function block gives me a number of datatype REAL. The Real must be converted to DWORD.
On the used platform the datatypes have the following sizes:

- REAL: 32 bits (4 bytes)
- DWORD: 32 bits (4 bytes)

So, what I think is that if just the bit representation is transferred between those two datatypes, the value won't change or loose precision.
What I am trying to do is the following:

```
myReal : REAL;
myDWord : DWORD;
myResultReal : REAL;

myReal := 0.819;

myDWord := REAL_TO_DWORD(myReal);
myResultReal := DWORD_TO_REAL(myDWord);

// myResultReal has value: 1
// Also when I check the bit string of the myDWord it differs from the actual
// bit string of myReal. Immediately after the first conversion.
```

The whole problem is just the rules of the programming language. Since both datatypes have the same memory size, it seems totally unnecessary to convert at all. The actual reason for converting is just because I need to pass my number to code later, that only accepts DWORD data types. It then uses the DWORD to get a REAL, but at that point the value is undesirably affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options. The fancier is the one that *pboedker* suggested: UNION data type.

Example:

```
TYPE U_TestUnion :
UNION
    Value_DWORD : DWORD;
    Value_REAL  : REAL;
END_UNION
END_TYPE   

VAR
    TestUnion   : U_TestUnion;
END_VAR

 TestUnion.Value_REAL := 0.819;
 //TestUnion.Value_DWORD is now 1062316540 (=16#3F51A9FC)

 TestUnion.Value_DWORD := 10; 
 //TestUnion.Value_REAL is now 1.401298E-44 

 TestUnion.Value_DWORD := 1062316540; 
 //TestUnion.Value_REAL is now 0.819
```

The other is the use MEMCPY function, that copies values from memory to other location. The function can named a little different in different systems. By doing this you can copy contents from the location of your REAL value to address of the DWORD and backwards.

In REAL->DWORD direction, there should be no worries. But when copying from DWORD to REAL, there might be some problems if there is any chance that the data has been modified anywhere. It might be possible that the value would be a **NaN** or **Infinity**, which might cause the PLC crash. This means that the REAL is not correctly formatted decimal number.

```
VAR
    Value_DWORD : DWORD;
    Value_REAL  : REAL;
END_VAR

Value_REAL := 0.819;
MEMCPY(destAddr:=ADR(Value_DWORD), srcAddr:=ADR(Value_REAL), n:=SIZEOF(Value_REAL));
 //Value_DWORD is now 1062316540 (=16#3F51A9FC)

Value_DWORD := 10; 
MEMCPY(destAddr:=ADR(Value_REAL), srcAddr:=ADR(Value_DWORD), n:=SIZEOF(Value_DWORD));
 //Value_REAL is now 1.401298E-44 

Value_DWORD := 1062316540; 
MEMCPY(destAddr:=ADR(Value_REAL), srcAddr:=ADR(Value_DWORD), n:=SIZEOF(Value_DWORD));
 //Value_REAL is now 0.819
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using conversion, so your REAL=0.819 will be converted to a DWORD=1 and back to a REAL=1. The bit representation will be changed accordingly at each conversion.

A solution to your problem is to use a UNION (IEC 61131-3). This way you can write into the REAL part, pass the DWORD part to your other code, and then again use the REAL part in that code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to multiply the real value by 10 n times before conversion, depending on the precision you want like so:

```
myReal := 0.819;

myDWord := REAL_TO_DWORD(myReal * 1000);
myResultReal := DWORD_TO_REAL(myDWord)/1000;
```

[image]